# Double "for loops" in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to do a quality control in a dataset with more than `3000` variables (columns). However, I only want to apply some conditions in a couple of them. A first step would be to replace outliers by `NA`. I want to replace the observations that are greater or smaller than `3` standard deviations from the `mean` by `NA`. I got it, doing column by column:

```
height = ifelse(abs(height-mean(height,na.rm=TRUE)) <
                           3*sd(height,na.rm=TRUE),height,NA)
```

And I also want to create other variables based on different columns. For example:

```
data$CGmark =   ifelse(!is.na(data$mark) & !is.na(data$height) ,
                                paste(data$age, data$mark,sep=""),NA)
```

An example  of my dataset would be:

```
name = factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","H"))
height = c(120,NA,150,170,NA,146,132,210,NA)
age = c(10,20,0,30,40,50,60,NA,130)
mark = c(100,0.5,100,50,90,100,NA,50,210)
data = data.frame(name=name,mark=mark,age=age,height=height)
data
```

I have tried this (for one condition):

```
d1=names(data)
list = c("age","height","mark")
ntraits=length(list)
nrows=dim(data)[1]
for(i in 1:ntraits){
a=list[i]
b=which(d1==a)
d2=data[,b]
for (j in 1:nrows){
                  d2[j] = ifelse(abs(d2[j]-mean(d2,na.rm=TRUE)) < 3*sd(d2,na.rm=TRUE),d2[j],NA)
                  }
}
```

Someone told me that I am not storing `d2`. How can I create `for loops` to apply the conditions I want? I know that there are similar questions but i didnt get it yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "How can I create efficient for loops to apply the conditions I want?" Just worry about making them work first. Worry about efficiency later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much wrote the answer in your first line. You're overthinking this one.

First, it's good practice to encapsulate this kind of operation in a function. Yes, function dispatch is a tiny bit slower than otherwise, but the code is often easier to read and debug. Same goes for assigning "helper" variables like `mean_x`: the cost of assigning the variable is very, very small and absolutely not worth worrying about.

```
NA_outside_3s <- function(x) {
    mean_x <- mean(x)
    sd_x <- sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)
    x_outside_3s <- abs(x - mean(x)) < 3 * sd_x
    x[x_outside_3s] <- NA  # no need for ifelse here
    x
}
```

of course, you can choose any function name you want. More descriptive is better.

Then if you want to apply the function to very column, just loop over the columns. That function `NA_outside_3s` is already vectorized, i.e. it takes a logical vector as an argument and returns a vector of the same length.

```
cols_to_loop_over <- 1:ncol(my_data)  # or, some subset of columns.
for (j in cols_to_loop_over) {
    my_data[, j] <- NA_if_3_sd(my_data[, j])
}
```

I'm not sure why you wrote your code the way you did (and it took me a minute to even understand what you were trying to do), but looping over columns is usually straightforward.

In my comment I said not to worry about efficiency, but once you understand how the loop works, you should rewrite it using `lapply`:

```
my_data[cols_to_loop_over] <- lapply(my_data[cols_to_loop_over], NA_outside_3s)
```

Once you know how the `apply` family of functions works, they are very easy to read if written properly. And yes, they are somewhat faster than looping, but not as much as they used to be. It's more a matter of style and readability.

Also: do NOT name a variable `list`! This masks the function `list`, which is an R built-in function and a fairly important one at that. You also shouldn't generally name variables `data` because there is also a `data` function for loading built-in data sets.

Comment: Thank you very much @ssdecontrol. You explained really well. Cheers.

Comment: @PaulaF glad to hear it helped. People often learn to use R without realizing they're learning a full fledged programming language, so they never learn to program properly. But taking the time to learn good coding practices now will save you a lot of trouble in the future, and make it easier to learn other programming languages if you want to.